# Excel - MAX date problems

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have column A as bin #, column B as PO #, and column C as expiration date. Each bin has multiple PO #s, i.e column A has 40 cells as bin 1. I am trying to use a pivot table to show the max expiration date for all POs in that bin# so that as new bins are added, the max expiration date automatically populates. Any help is appreciated and my apologies if I did not explain my problem or end goal sufficiently.

Comment: The absence of a representative data sample makes it hard to know what problem you are having.  So far as "automatically populates", Pivot tables don't do that by themselves. You'd have to add VBA Event code to execute a Refresh on the Pivot table for that to happen.

Comment: Thanks Ron, that alone is helpful.

Comment: Depending on your excel version, you might be able to create a faux pivot table by using the formulas: `=UNIQUE()` and `MAXIFS()` . If done right, this will automatically update when you add data...

Comment: @MVUser,, you have BIN # and each bin has multiple POs with Expiry Date and you are looking for latest date (max),, this can be solved by worksheet function, possibly by Power Pivot too, but better [edit] your post & share some sample data, help us to fix it !

Comment: Solved! Thanks for the help!